# Cassandra Delete Records

Tags: cassandra

I'm new to Cassandra and I've been having some issues trying to delete records. I have a table defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE wire_journal (
    persistence_id text,
    partition_nr bigint,
    sequence_nr bigint,
    timestamp timeuuid,
    timebucket text,
    event blob,
    event_manifest text,
    message blob,
    ser_id int,
    ser_manifest text,
    tag1 text,
    tag2 text,
    tag3 text,
    used boolean static,
    writer_uuid text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((persistence_id, partition_nr), sequence_nr, timestamp, timebucket)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (sequence_nr ASC, timestamp ASC, timebucket ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'bucket_high': '1.5', 'bucket_low': '0.5', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'enabled': 'true', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_sstable_size': '50', 'min_threshold': '4', 'tombstone_compaction_interval': '86400', 'tombstone_threshold': '0.2', 'unchecked_tombstone_compaction': 'false'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

And Indexes defined as follows:

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX timestamp_idx ON wire_journal (timestamp) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex';
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX manifest_idx ON wire_journal (event_manifest) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex';
```

I would like to be able to delete by timestamp and event_manifest.

I can query by an event manifest for example:

```
select event_manifest, dateOf(timestamp) from wire_journal where event_manifest = '011000028';
```

The query above works. However If I try to do a deletion for the same criteria as follows:

```
delete from wire_journal where event_manifest = '011000028';
```

I get the following error:

InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Some partition key parts are missing: persistence_id, partition_nr"

I've tried including those columns in my delete as follows:

```
delete persistence_id, partition_nr from wire_journal where event_manifest = 'aba:011000028';
```

and I get the following error:

invalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid identifier persistence_id for deletion (should not be a PRIMARY KEY part)"

How can I go about deleting all the records that match that condition?

Answer (score 2):

Your partition key is (persistence_id, partition_nr) and Cassandra only delete records using partition key

So your query need to be like:

`delete from wire_journal where persistence_id = x AND partition_nr = y AND event_manifest = 'aba:011000028';`